# Azure Functions V2 have to stop functions every time before publishing because dll is busy

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So this is new on V2, when I publish with Visual Studio (probably with vsts publishing as well). It says the dll is busy, it didn't used to do that in V1.

I suppose it's fine to stop the functions (Or probably I can do slot deployment as well, although all mine are triggered and scheduled, so I don't really need slots).
So on the "stop" it will still do that 30 seconds of graceful stop that the functions do before shutting down / switching (Heard this on a podcast when I asked).
If I redeploy after the stop, I suppose it's ok this way. Things will wait on my triggers from azure queue and schedule.

Only thing is it's sort of a pain to have to press start and stop rather than just publish. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be doing this or not. Doesn't seem publish will ever work unless it's stopped, why not have it auto-stop the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you meet [ERROR_FILE_IN_USE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#errorfileinuse)
.

You can configure the appOffline rule in the publishing profile (In Solution explorer> Properties>PublishProfiles>*.pubxml). Set the EnableMSDeployAppOffline to true as below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

This setting take the app offline so the file lock is released and your app will start automatically after deploy.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that ZIP deployment is now preferred, the solution to this is to add an app setting MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES with value 1.